# Apache MINA decoder classes explained

Tags: java, apache-mina

I'm currently digging into Apache MINA. It's a great framework with lots of capabilities. The hardest part until now was the decoder part. Checking the api documents I understand that there are the following classes that one can extend and implement his own:

1. **DemuxingProtocolDecoder** - A composite ProtocolDecoder that demultiplexes incoming IoBuffer decoding requests into an appropriate MessageDecoder.
2. **ObjectSerializationDecoder** - A ProtocolDecoder which deserializes Serializable Java objects using IoBuffer.getObject(ClassLoader).
3. **PrefixedStringDecoder** - A ProtocolDecoder which decodes a String using a fixed-length length prefix.

All of the above extend the **CumulativeProtocolDecoder** class - A ProtocolDecoder that cumulates the content of received buffers to a cumulative buffer to help users implement decoders.

- Could you please mention with some real world examples what subclass of CumulativeProtocolDecoder you would or did use and why?
- Is there an example that doesn't need the decoder to extend the CumulativeProtocolDecoder class and just implement the ProtocolDecoder directly without worrying about fragmentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using an instance of DemuxingProtocolDecoder class with my application. Under the package `org.apache.mina.filter.codec.demux` there are some interfaces and classes that you can use to decode your messages. There is an interface called `MessageDecoder`. Create your own class that implements this interface and MINA will the work. Something like this,

```
public class MyDecoder implements MessageDecoder {
      public MessageDecoderResult decode(IoSession session, IoBuffer buffer, ProtocolDecoderOutput decoderOutput) throws Exception {
           /* Your
              decode
              mechanism */
           decoderOutput.write(message); // don't forget to write your decoded message object at some point.
           return MessageDecoder.OK; //or something else that matches your needs.
      }
}
```